# Want to zip 7 days older log files and then move to diffenrent directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Although this question may be a duplicate one but I can find the appropriate answer for this question. I can find 7 days older log files and move them to different directory but before moving them to different directory I want to zipped them within a single file and them move the zipped file.

```
root@tryit-becoming:~/home# find /root/home/logs -mtime -8 -exec mv '{}' /root/home/ \;
```

this is my code

Comment: Not sure to understand clearly, but if you want to get several files in one zip, the best approach would be to tar them first then zip the tarball as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Something like the following might work, but would probably fail with weird file names (including line feeds at least or maybe even spaces) : `find /root/home/logs -mtime -8 | zip -@ /root/home/archive.zip`

Comment: @AndreGelinas the problem would be the same, you'd have to find a way to provide `tar` with the path of the files you want archived.

Comment: Well depends, moving those old logs can be done in a known temp directory. Then you tar that directory, zip the tarball and finally removed the temp directory. End result is a zipped tarball containing all the old logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
find /root/home/logs -mtime -8 -exec zip /root/home/file.zip {} +
```

Comment: If there are too many files `zip` will be executed multiple times, which I believe will result in a final zip only containing the parameters of the last invocation

Comment: Actually just add `-u` to zip's options and this should be fine : it will update the zip if it already exists and create it otherwise (complaining in the process). This would however rely on OP making sure the previous version of the archive isn't present anymore at the specified location

Comment: Hi @Incrivel Monstro Verde....I want the files to be moved after zipping all them

Comment: try find /var/log  -mtime -8 -exec zip /tmp/file.zip {} \; -exec rm {} +
worked here

Comment: It looks like you could also use `zip`'s `-m` / `--move` flag. Quoting the man : "actually, this deletes the  target  directories/files  after  making  the specified  zip archive"